# Reference request: Positive solution of positive system of linear equations

Tags: reference-request, matrices, positivity

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be an invertible matrix with positive entries,
and $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ a vector with positive entries.

When does $A^{-1}b$ have all positive entries?
I am looking for references to sufficient (or, ideally, equivalent) conditions.

So far, I found only one by [M. Kaykobad (1985)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002437958590271X):
If
$$
b_i > \sum_{j\neq i} A_{ij} \frac{b_j}{A_{jj}}
$$
for all $i=1,\dots,n,$ then $A^{-1}b$ has all positive entries.

Maybe we can use the fact that $A^{-1}$ is an $M$-matrix, or there are some results from probability theory?

Comment: [A new characterization of inverse-positive matrices](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0024-3795(91)90372-4) (1991)

Comment: Thank you! How can I apply this to my problem? The situation in the paper seems to be the other way around: In my notation, it deals with $Ab$, not $A^{-1}b$.